# Taylor series coefficients of general rational function

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

Given two (possibly infinite) sequences of complex numbers $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots\}$ and $\{b_1, b_2, \ldots\}$, I'm looking to find a closed form expression for each element of the sequence of complex numbers $\{c_1, c_2, \ldots\}$ where the sequences are related by

$$\frac{1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n}{1+\sum_{m=1}^\infty b_m x^m} = 1+\sum_{r=0}^\infty c_r x^r\,.$$

Essentially, I am looking for a rapid computational algorithm to find the Taylor series expansion coefficients of a general rational function.

---

Edit: The problem can be simplified to finding a series expansion of $(1+\sum_{m=1}^\infty b_m x^m)^{-1}$ since then the $c$ coefficients are given by the series product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Hint:** The coefficients $c_r$ in terms of *determinants* of the coefficients of $1+\sum_{m=1}^\infty b_m x^m$ can be found *[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050216/dividing-an-infinite-power-series-by-another-infinite-power-series/2053177#2053177)*.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want
to compute the coefficients,
here is the standard way:

[Dividing an infinite power series by another infinite power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050216/dividing-an-infinite-power-series-by-another-infinite-power-series/2053177#2053177)